# Accessing Fixture Data outside of "it" function in Cypress Tests

Tags: javascript, testing, integration-testing, cypress

I would like to programmatically write a series of `it()` tests given the data from a fixture (which seems like the correct way of using data in Cypress) or elsewhere.

This data is an array of objects, each object provides the necessary information needed for each `it()` test I'd like to write.

```js
[
  {
    slug: "/some-page-with-form/",
    slugRedir: "/expected-redir-page-after-form-submit/",
    formData: [
      {
        htmlName: "firstName",
        type: "inputText",
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Below is an idea of what I'm trying to achieve

```
describe("CMS-generated pages with forms", function() {
    before(function() {
        cy.fixture("forms").as("forms")
    });

    this.forms.forEach(({ slug, slugRedir, formData }) => {
        it(`fills and submits form on ${slug}`, function() {
            ...
        });
    })
})
```

Obviously the above doesn't work because `this.forms` is `undefined` outside of the `it()` scope.

To summarize - how would I achieve programmatically writing a series of `it()` tests given the data from either a fixture or possibly imported elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you do that. You're essentially trying to automate generating tests, and I can understand the impulse but I suggest putting the work in to write the tests. This will give you an opportunity to ask what you're trying to test, if you really need the test, and what the results mean.

If you really think it wise, you could always have a catch-all test for forms such as:

```
it(`fills and submits forms', function () {
  this.forms.forEach(({ ... }) => {
    // assertions
  })
})
```

To answer the original question, you can also make the data available simply by importing it:

```
import forms from '../fixtures/forms.json'

// ...

  forms.forEach(...)
```

Comment: I disagree, there are plenty of reasonable cases to use data driven tests and most test frameworks provide a way to do this already.

Comment: Mmm, I'm not really convinced. While there may be appropriate times to automate test generation, I don't believe this to be one of them. Too many assumptions. If the CMS generates forms and the response to them, that behaviour should certainly be tested, but if behaviour varies based on the slug used I'd want to see that defined by specific tests that demonstrate the edge cases, not hidden in a fixture. It makes it so much easier when the tests serve as documentation when entering a new project.

Comment: Specific to the OP's case, I agree.  I was commenting more for the sake of future people who land on this question in their googling.

Comment: Simple use case - visit a collection of URL's and check that the page title is an expected value. Surely it would make sense to iterate over a collection of URL + expected value pairs, rather than copy and paste what is essentially the same test multiple times? Or would you suggest iterating over the assertions within, rather than the whole test?

Answer (score 0):

You're close, [you can't use arrow functions and `this` in the same spec](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Avoiding-the-use-of-this), you can either convert to non-arrow functions or try one of these.

EDIT:  Removed my solutions.  After I posted similar solutions, I found this already answered in a cypress issue here:  https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3963#issuecomment-483581934